# Where to put global state in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

In my Ember.js application users can have multiple projects. Since only one project can be viewed at a time, the active project is selected via the navigation bar. This is basically a global state (which is also reflected in the URL `/projects/xyz`).

**Since multiple components depend on the project selection, where do I put this information? And in what form do I save it (instance or id)?**

---

*About my status quo*: I have a route that intercepts the call to `setupController` for `/projects/:project_id` and uses `App.set("projectId", model)` to place the instance in the global namespace. This seems bad, doesn't it?

Comment: Maybe you can just use localStorage? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage#localStorage

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whenever you have global state that is reflected in the url you can use the ember router to manage that state.

For example, let's say you have a tasks resource nested under project like:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('project', { path: '/projects/:project_id' }, function() {
    this.route('edit');
    this.resource('tasks', function() {
      this.route('new');
    });
  });
});
```

Ember will use the project_id url segment to find your model and set it as the content of ProjectController. To access the currently selected project from another controller, declare a dependency using the `needs` array and access it via the `controllers` property.

```
App.TasksController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  needs: ['project']
});

// tasks/index.hbs
Project name: {{controllers.project.name}}
```

See [controllers-needs-explained](http://darthdeus.github.com/blog/2013/01/27/controllers-needs-explained/)